# why qsort need exactly 4 byte for sorting string literal?

Tags: c, pointers

Suppose I have the following code:

```
char *a[] = {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five"};
qsort(a, sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0], 4, comp)  // Doesn't matter what comp function is
```

As you can see, I've passed 3rd argument as 4. (I can pass also sizeof(char*) or sizeof(int), both works).

As I know, different strings takes different space ( it can be greater than 4 or less than also). So, why `qsort` need exactly 4 byte as 3rd argument?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you don't have an array of strings (i. e. an array of arrays [of different size]) -- all you have is an array of **pointers** (to the first characters of the strings).

---

(by the way, you really should be declaring the array of pointers as `const char *a[]`.)

Comment: So, it means all string literal take same space (i.e., 4)

Comment: @ashish2expert No. The string literals take up 4, 4, 6, 5, and 5 bytes, respectively.

Comment: So, if I want to go to 2nd string in my case by using only address, how much I need to add to previous address

Comment: NO @ashish2expert it means every pointer(an address) takes same place(i.e 4). But the size of data pointed by pointer may vary.

Comment: @ashish2expert which address?

Comment: suppose string "one" has address 104040, how much i need to add to this address

Comment: @ashish2expert starting address of the array where string stored.

Comment: I know this, but will this means every new string in array of pointers  start at `previous address + 4`

Comment: @ashish2expert Every **pointer** in the array of pointers will start at previous address + 4.

Answer (score 5):

Because it's not sorting string literals, it's sorting `char *`s (which are pointing to those strings). On your system, pointers are four bytes (32 bits).

Answer (score 2):

Each element of the your string is a char pointer. A pointer type has 4 byte if you compile your program as a 32 Bit application. If you compile it as a 64 Bit application the size of the pointer type will be 8 byte.